# Exported gltf Looks Like Plastic

Tags: materials, 3d-view

I am a newbie to blender. I am trying to learn to build 3D buildings for the new Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020. I have the I have the MSFSToolkit extension installed and I am using Blender 2.91.

MSFS suggests exporting to gltf, bin, and xml, so that is what I am doing.

For now, I am just trying to export a simple cube that has a stucco material applied to it. The material was created with nodes.

[image: As rendered in Blender]

As Rendered in Blender

[image: After Cycles Baking]

After Cycles Baking

[image: Material Nodes Setup]

Material Node Setup

[image: As Rendered in Game]

As Rendered in Game

[image: As Rendered by Windows 3D Viewer]

As Rendered by Windows 3D Viewer

I would imagine that I am missing one or more important steps.

Does anyone know of a good video tutorial that covers what I am trying to do, or can you see right off the bat what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The BumpStucco node isn't connected to anything. The exporter will also ignore the bump/noise nodes.

Comment: @scurest, thank you. What do you suggest that I connect the BumpStucco node to? Also, if the exporter ignores bump/noise nodes, will my cube still render in the game in the same way that it does in blender? If not, how do I get around that?

Comment: The Base Color I guess? No, it won't render the same. If you want to connect something to the Normal socket, it has to be normal map (see the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.91/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#normal-map)).